# jquery file download plugin doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) to make it possible to download files or at least I try to but it won't work.

I put the mentioned cookie in my index.php at top position like this:

```
header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/');
```

The cookie is set, I can see that in the site information.
My js code on the current site looks like this:

```
$('.js--download').on('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $.fileDownload(target)
    .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
    .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
    return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
});
```

The problem is that the **.done** function is fired but the download didn't start. I also wonder why I can see now request send by the network in my browser inspect tool. When it's really an ajax call I should see it there.

So, someone with an idea?